# Given an integer n, return the largest number that contains exactly n digits. Why Codefights don't accept it?

Tags: javascript

```js
const largestNumber = (n) => {
  let arr = [];
  let arr2 = [];
  let maxNum = 9;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  for (let j = 1; j <= arr.length; j++) {
    arr2.push(maxNum)
  }
  let s = arr2.join("");
  return s;
}
console.log(largestNumber(10))
```

Result Show: Error Output:Empty

Comment: Your function returns a string, but the question is looking for a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be returning that is a `string` type and result may be expected a `number` type. You just have to return type `number` as

```
return +s;
```

or

```
return parseInt(s)
```

**1)** There is no need to loop through after creating an array. Alternatively you can do as

```js
const largestNumber = (n) => {
  return Math.pow(10, n) - 1;
};
console.log(largestNumber(10));
```

**2)** You can also achieve the same result with [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
const length = 10;
const result = Array.from({ length }, () => 9).join("");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned the test is looking for a number but the function returns a string.

HR01M8055's answer is great. Here's mine which uses an array and returns a number.

```js
function largestNumber(n) {
  return Number(Array(n).fill(9).join(''));
}

const result = largestNumber(10);

console.log(typeof result, result);
```

Comment: [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is also a better option. If I'm not wrong. But I don't know which one is efficient `Array(n).fill(9).join('')` or `Array.from({ length }, () => 9).join("")`. Have a look at my answer. I've added another solution